# Reduce large number to intword in Django without editing template

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am developing a web application that displays an html table using django, django-tables2 and Bootstrap4. I have a column `AUM` which contains very large numbers (up to billions). In my `models.py` the corresponding model uses a `models.Interfield()` for `AUM`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    AUM = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)
    ...
```

Using django-tables2 and Bootstrap4 this model gets transformed into a table and rendered into a template using

```
{% render_table table %}
```

The numbers displayed in the corresponding column a displayed in there raw format which looks like e.g. this 1000000000. I want to make it more human readable. I have found two solutions for seperating thousands

- Using `intcomma` from `django.contrib.humanize` which is not a viable solution for me as it requires me to add a filter in the template which I cannot do as I am just adding `{% render_table table %}`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/humanize/)
- Using the global setting `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True`in my `settings.py`which is a solution that works great for me (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#use-thousand-separator)

I have also seen that there is something similar to `intcomma` which is `intword` and it transforms e.g. 1000000 into 1 Million which is in my opinion even more human readable. As with the `intcomma` this is not a viable solution for me, which is why I am looking for a global setting like `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True` however for displaying 1000000 as 1 Million (or Mio.) not 1,000,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django-tables2 allows using a [`TemplateColumn`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#templatecolumn) to use the django templating language for a cell. This does require you to create a custom table:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    "django.contrib.humanize",
    "django_tables2"
    # ...
)


# tables.py

import django_tables2 as tables


class MyTable(tables.Table):
    AUM = tables.TemplateColumn(
        template_code="{% load humanize %}{{ value | intword }}"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        sequence = ("AUM", "...")  # using "..." here will automatically add the remaining columns of the model to the table.

# views.py

class MyView(SingleTableView):
    table_class = MyTable
```